# What happened to Lenovo LePhone? Is it on the market? Was it released?

Tags: keyboard

I found a lot of adds, [comparisons](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=pdacomparer&id=39&c=android_smartphones_with_qwerty_keyboard), and [presentations of Lenovo LePhone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvdYnvImlq0), mostly from January 2010, but on earth I cannot find any store where to buy it! Was it released at last?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It was released, but only in China](http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/business/2011-08/09/content_13076594.htm):

> In May 2010, the company launched its 2,899-yuan LePhone, which China Unicom sold 145,000 units after hitting the market, to compete with Apple's 4,999-yuan iPhone4.

Comment: OMG, why only in China???

Comment: Only Lenovo can answer that.